# Best way to have "timed out" operations with web services?

Tags: c#, web-services, timeout

I've got some web services that are going to be used by a web application to fetch data from and write to the database. There are some operations that can only be done by one user at a time, so the database keeps track of if someone is doing one of those operations and won't let anyone else do them if this is the case. I want to implement a time out though. So if the user has something locked for more than 10 minutes then they time out and their lock gets revoked.

The only way that comes to mind to do this is to have a service/application running on the server, with some manner of elevated privileges, either directly removing the lock from the database or using a web service that only it has access to to remove said lock. This seems kind of hacky to me though, so I thought I'd ask the SO community if there's a better/cleaner/more common way I could accomplish this.

Comment: How could something be locked for 10 minutes?  Are the users initiating the action that acquires the lock, and are they also initiating the action that releases the lock?  (most of the time when you lock something, you do so atomically in a single request/transaction, where it doesn't make sense for a lock to exist for that long.

Comment: @KirkWoll I don't mean a kind of data-transactional lock, I mean "editing a case file" kind of lock

Comment: @KirkWoll And yea, they're doing an operation to initiate the lock, and then when they're done they do something else to cancel the lock

Comment: Right, makes sense.  Your approach sounds fine, but why would your service/application require "elevated" privileges?  Presumably your codebase has full db privileges on the database, and you secure your system via app-code, no?  (in which case, elevated privileges wouldn't make sense...)